# Word comparison - Vectors /Getopt

Tags: c++, command-line, arguments, stdvector

My understanding of `getopt` is very limited.
I do however realise that `argv[0]` is the exe file, `argv[1]` is the option, `argv[2]` is the word to compare and `argv[3]` is the dictionary or document I want to search (file `.txt`).

I'm trying to set a pointer to the dictionary and then iterate through it to see if there is a match with the `argv[2]` (input word) to the text file, and if there is a match output the `argv[2]` word.
Below is my current code that has errors:

```
main.cpp:61: error: no match for 'operator==' in 'list == *(argv + 12u)'
main.cpp:64: error: no match for 'operator*' in '*list'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std; 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    enum {
        WHOLE, PREFIX, SUFFIX, ANYWHERE, EMBEDDED
    } mode = WHOLE;
    bool jumble = false;
    bool ignore_case = false;
    bool invert = false;
    string length = "0,0";
    int c;
    string input;
    vector <string> list;
    vector <string>::iterator i;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, ":wpsaejivn:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'w': mode = WHOLE;
                break;
            case 'p': mode = PREFIX;
                break;
            case 's': mode = SUFFIX;
                break;
            case 'a': mode = ANYWHERE;
                break;
            case 'e': mode = EMBEDDED;
                break;
            case 'j': jumble = true;
                break;
            case 'i': ignore_case = true;
                break;
            case 'v': invert = true;
                break;
            case 'n': length = optarg;
                break;
            default: WHOLE;
                break;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    switch (mode) {
        case WHOLE:
            while(argc != -1){
                list == argv[3];
                for(i == list.begin(); i != list.end(); i++)
                if(argv[1] == argv[3]){
                    cout << *list << endl;
                }else cout << "Did not work again" << endl;
            }                                  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without going into logic and what the code is doing, the two problems i see with the code (and the two problem that is reported by compiler): 1. `list == argv[3]`. `list` is a `vector` and you are comparing it with `const char *`. 2.  `cout << *list << endl`. Did you mean `*i` here? `std::vector` doesn't have `operator *` defined.

Comment: Another problem: `while(argc != -1)`. This, without decrementing `argc` inside the loop, will result into an infinite loop.

Comment: The idea was to compare arg[2] (input word) with arg[3] (.txt file), i just noticed if(argv[1] == argv[3]), should have been if(argv[2] == argv[3]).

Comment: How would i go about fixing the issues, so the input word searches the text file, and prints out a result if the word exists in the text file.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you won't be needing a vector here. You need to read the file argv[3], parse it word by word and stop when you find a word that equals argv[2].

I image you want something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
  // The part where you parse the input and validate it
  // ...

  // Read the dictionary specified in argv[3] and compare it with argv[2] line by line
  ifstream input_file(argv[3]);
  string match_string(argv[2]);
  string current_string;
  bool found = false;
  while(getline(input_file, current_string) && !found)
      found = (current_string.compare(match_string) == 0);

  // Check the result
  if (found)
     cout << "Found " << match_string << " in " << argv[3] << endl;
  else
     cout << "Did not work again" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In this basic solution I assume that every word in the dictionary file is in a separate line. Of course you need to modify this according to your needs, and also add more input validation as necessary.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Without going into `getopt`, which I do not think is your problem here, I'll answer the question that given a file with list of words and a word, how do you determine if the word is present in the file.

There can be many ways to do this, but conceptually it involves following steps:

1. Read the input file and create a dictionary out of it.
2. Match the input word in your dictionary.

Code snippet:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Input file stream
  std::ifstream file_in(argv[3]);

  // Iterators to iterate over input file
  std::istream_iterator<std::string> in_begin(file_in), in_end;

  // Create a dictionary of words.
  // Using std::set for this.
  std::set<std::string> dictionary(in_begin, in_end);

  // Word to find in dictionary
  std::string word(argv[2]);

  // See if the word is present in our dictionary
  if(dictionary.find(word) != dictionary.end())
    std::cout << word << " found in " << argv[3] << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << word << " not found in " << argv[3] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: First line of the code block is `#include <fstream>`. Which SO is interpreting as something else. I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: @ssjeitan, yeah I was trying to fix this `#include` thing :-)

Comment: @ssjeitan, k, fixed. I was not trying to replicate exactly what OP was doing. I was trying to give an example of how to read a file into a container and find something in a container.

Comment: The example is clear, but from a practical point of view it wouldn't be smart to load the entire dictionary into the memory. It appears that you're iterating over the dictionary twice: once for loading and once for string-matching.

Comment: @ssjeitan, it is not unless you want to reuse your dictionary. However the idea of this answer was to correct two code error OP was making, and explain him a good way to do those things 1. `list == argv[3]`. Here i believe he wants to load the words from file to a container. I wanted to give an example on how to do it correctly. 2. Iterating over container to find a word. Using `find`, i wanted to show correct way to find something in a container.

Comment: Yes, `list == argv[3]` was indeed _how_ the OP was trying to implement, but it's not necessarily the best way, judging by the question. I guess this answer might also suit him, but that only the OP can say :)